# Como puedo mostrar el valor de una variable por pantalla dentro de un texto en c#?

Tags: c#, consola

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de escritorio y quiero mostrar el valor de una variable por pantalla dentro de las comillas este es mi código

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int casa = 16;


        Console.WriteLine("variable {{casa}}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Imprime `casa` no `16`, se puede hacer sumando y el nombre de la variable pero yo lo quiero dentro de las comillas se podría hacer ???

Comment: Lo que quieres conseguir se llama interpolación de cadenas y tienes toda la informacion [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: No tiene mucho que ver esa pregunta con mi pregunta ya que  pido varias formas de mostrar una variable por pantalla

Comment: @ortiga si tiene que ver, ya que la interpolación de cadenas es una de las formas de mostrar una variable en un string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para mostrar el valor de la variable existen dos formas:

Colocando la variable luego del operador `+`, afuera de los `""`

**1)** `Console.WriteLine("variable" + casa);`

O esta segunda opción está *disponible solamente* para **C# >= 6.0**. Colocar el símbolo `$` luego del paréntesis de inicio y colocando el nombre de la variable entre `{}` dentro de las `""`:

**2** `Console.WriteLine($"variable {casa}");`

Un saludo.

Comment: Yo añadiría que la segunda opción solo está disponible a partir de C#6.0

Comment: "Colocar el símbolo $ luego del paréntesis de inicio" en realidad el $ va antes de las comillas de cadena, por ejemplo: var x = $"variable {casa}". Lo aclaro para que no se preste a confusión y que se piense que solo se usa con WriteLine.

Answer (score 3):

Tener varias opciones, las dos más comunes, serían,

**Concatenar**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int casa = 16;
        Console.WriteLine("variable "+ casa);
        //Mostraría variable 16
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

O también, podrías armar un string con [**String.Format**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx), pero ya aplicaría, quizas, a situaciones mas particulares

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int casa = 16;
        String texto = String.Format("La variable es {0}.",
                     casa);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        //Mostraría La variable es 16
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Como te decía anteriormente, tenés infinidad de manera de hacer lo que buscas, sería cuestión de buscar cúal es la que es más cómoda para vos

Saludos